# What type of method does not modify the object on which it is invoked?

Tags: java

I couldn't remember the name of the method. Can someone explain to me and also provide me the name of this method.

Comment: A [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) free method.

Comment: It is called an accessor method because it only accesses, but not modifies the object it uses. A method that does modify the object on which is invoked is called a mutator method. I`d answer the question, unfortunately it is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're either thinking of **immutable** objects in object-oriented programming, whose methods cannot modify the observable state of the object.

Or, **pure** functions, which in part are functions that do not have side-effects.  They take in inputs, and produce resulting outputs. They do not modify anything that can be accessed outside the execution of the function (including the input data passed in).

Additionally, as pointed out by @aioobe in the comment below, **pure** functions always return the same value for the same given input.

Comment: The definition of pure also requires the method to return the same value when invoked again, so I'd say pure is slightly stronger than just side-effect free.

Comment: @aioobe.  You're right.  I'll update my answer!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it helped me. I don't know why the others give me " - " but I understand now.  That's important.

Comment: @HaydarÖztürk. Yours is a legit question. In C++ you can specify a method as "const" meaning that it can't modify the properties of the object (unless those properties are marked as "mutable"). This is very helpful for "Exception-Safe" code, where you can remain aware of what objects have potentially been modified and potentially corrupted,  in the case of an Exception. There is no "const" equivalent for methods in Java (marking methods as final for example will just mean you can't override them; yet you can still modify the class properties.)